# LD needs DWARF version 3 or 2, but mine is version 4

Tags: gcc, qt5, ld, taglib, dwarf

After hours of research (and tries) on how to install `id3lib` on Qt (windows), but with no success, I decided to use [TagLib's library](http://taglib.github.io/).

I followed [this tutorial](http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-compile-taglib-on-windows/) to build a compatible version of taglib for Qt but still another problem ([full log here](http://f.cl.ly/items/3t062V0b3O0o271D2P2N/cmake_error.txt)):

```
  ...

  C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf
  Error: found dwarf version '4', this reader only handles version 2 and 3
  information.

  C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../mingw32/lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1f1):
  undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'

  ...
```

In CMake, I did `configure` > `MinGW Makefiles`.

Can anyone tell how to fix it?

Environment:

- Windows 7 (64-bit);
- CMake 2.8.12.1;
- TagLib 1.9.1;
- GCC 3.4.5;
- Qt 5.1.1.

Comment: ok, I am updating gcc. I'll try to rebuild.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you are using terribly outdated GCC, while your Qt binaries are most likely built with bleeding-edge GCC (or the one close to it). For instance, as the error message shows, DWARF is outdated in case of your current GCC and is incompatible with the one used by your current Qt. Furthermore, even if it wouldn't, you'd still hit other problems with binary incompatibilities, since you essentially mix compilers with different *major* version numbers, which is strongly discouraged. Notice, that your problem has nothing to do with CMake at all. You can see it yourself in the error message, i.e. the error is reported by `ld`, the linker utility from (your outdated) GCC toolchain. To conclude, your only option is to update GCC, ideally exactly to the one which was used to build your current Qt.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, do you think I can use the passes.c of an older gcc version with the new one ? (compiling from source the gcc 4.9 i.e and then use the modified passes.c to control ove the phases ?)